# How can I get the PHP not to send the message empty?

Tags: php, email, message, send, sendmessage

I'm supposed to recieve some type of information but nothing. I've checked many times but I keep getting an empty message and I know I've placed everything right. I don't know what's wrong, help please

```
<?php

    $from = 'How to join contact form <contact@choice.md>';
    $sendTo = 'Name Lastname <namelastname@choice.md>';
    $subject = 'How to join contact form';
    $fields = array('name1' =>'Full Name', 'email1' => 'Email', 'phone1' =>'Phone',
                    'address1' =>'Address','message1' =>'Message');
    $okMessage = 'Patient contact form successfully submitted';
    $errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting';

    try
    {
        $emailText = "You have new message from How to Join Contact Form\n\n";

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

           if (isset($fields[$key])) {
               $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
            'From: ' . $from,
            'Reply-To: ' . $from,
            'Return-Path: ' . $from,
        );

        mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: You know that you do nothing with ` $responseArray` ?

Comment: When you say empty message, are you referring to the email message? Are you getting to this script by submitting a form with `method="post"`?

Comment: Is the message missing the "You have new message" boilerplate?

Comment: Using the mail function will have limited success. Ideally you would use SMTP on your server, or be connecting externally to an SMTP email service like gmail. Try sending email to mailtrap.io, and look at all the warnings. Unless you use SMTP, nobody really knows who you are, and in this age that equals your email being dropped or being marked as spam.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes that's what I'm referring to and yes I am

Comment: @GiDo please explain